# Pearson correlation coefficient 2-tailed p-value meaning

Tags: python, math, numpy, statistics, scipy

from the sciPy library I used: scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr to calculate the correlation coefficient for two arrays and I got a value of: (0.80751532276005755, 0.19248467723994242).

I thought that I would have just got one value within the range -1 to +1, so I'm unsure how to interpret these two results. These are my two arrays:

```
x = [50,500,1500,2500]
y = [17, 6, 6, 194]
```

and I did:

```
pearsonr(x,y)
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation for that function?

Comment: Yes but I'm not entirely sure about the meaning of a 2-tailed p-value. So the first value is the correlation  and the second value the probability of an uncorrealted set producing the same result.

Comment: This should, now , be moved to the stats forum.  It is a basic stats question.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`pearsonr()` returns a two-tuple consisting of the correlation coefficient and the corresponding p-value:

- The correlation coefficient can range from -1 to +1.
- The null hypothesis is that the two variables are uncorrelated. The p-value is a number between zero and one that represents the probability that your data would have arisen if the null hypothesis were true.

For a further discussion, see http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~norman/blog_articles/p_values.pdf

> I thought that I would have just got one value within the range -1 to +1

If you just need to the correlation coefficient, simply ignore the second element of the tuple (the p-value):

```
corrxy = pearsonr(x,y)[0]
```

It might be worth mentioning that there's also [`numpy.corrcoef()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html), which computes the correlation matrix (without p-values).

Comment: I'll also take a look at the numpy method. Thanks for the explanation.